# Norm of Hermite polynomials in a non-standard Gaussian

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hermite-polynomials

The Hermite polynomials I am using satisfy the recurrence $H_k'(x) = kH_{k-1}(x)$ and they satisfy the property if $d\mu_{1/2} = (2\pi)^{-1/2}e^{-x^2/2}$ is the standard Gaussian then $||H_k||_{L^2(\mu_{1/2})}^2 = k!$. For instance, $H_2(x) = x^2 - 1$, and $H_3(x) = x^3 - 3x$, and $H_4(x) = x^4 - 6x^2 + 3$.

Is there a simple formula for obtaining the norm of the same Hermite polynomials but wrt another Gaussian measure? That is, if $d\mu_\alpha = (4\pi \alpha)^{-1/2}e^{-\alpha x^2}$ is another normalized Gaussian, is there a simple formula for $||H_k||_{L^2(\mu_\alpha)}^2$ in terms of $\alpha$ and $k$? Or are there lower and upper bounds?

Even for $\alpha = 1$ the only way I see I can move forward with this calculation is making the substitution $x = y/\sqrt{2}$ so that $||H_k||_{L^2(\mu_\alpha)}^2 = \int_{\mathbb R} H_k(x)^2d\mu_1(x) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb R} H_k(y/\sqrt{2})^2d\mu_{1/2}(y)$ is the norm of a scaled Hermite polynomial with respect to the standard Gaussian. But I don't know any ways to control this integral.

Comment: I don't know an answer to your question, but I'd be skeptical that there is a general approach to this, because the standard Hermite polynomials are, from my viewpoint, created from that special Gaussian by applying "raising/creation" operators to the Gaussian. And that structure allows (in my perception) the computation of norms, and other things. Changing the Gaussian still allows a similar structure (with raising and lowering operators), but the corresponding Hermite polys are different.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I was hoping for some structure to exploit, but if you think this is unlikely then perhaps I will try brute force (expand the Hermite polynomial and use formulas for the norms of monomials).

Comment: And/or maybe express one-type Hermite polynomials (attached to one-type of Gaussian) in terms of another-type Hermite polynomials (attached to a different Gaussian)? ... The decomposition coefficients (if there happened to be some pattern...) would answer your question. This "reversal" of the question seems slightly more promising to me... But, still, dunno. I've never tried it. :)

Comment: Hermite polynomials are obtained from monomials $x^n$ by running the heat flow backward in time, ie, applying hitting them with the "differential" operator $\exp(-t\Delta)$ where the time $t$ is specified by the variance of the associated Gaussian measure. So the new Hermite should be the old ones hit by such an operator with $t$ being the difference of times. I don't know how ugly the formulas would be, but it can be done.

Comment: So is your suggestion that I can think of $||H_k||_{L^2_\alpha}^2 = ||e^{-t\Delta}H_k||_{L^2_{1/2}}^2$ for some correct $t > 0$, and since I can write down a summation formula for $e^{-t\Delta}H_k$ in terms of (I guess) $H_{k-2}, H_{k-4}, \cdots$ then I might be able to estimate the norm in this way? I guess this would get me an upper bound and not an upper bound right?